# How can I flag an off-topic question without selecting an off-topic reason?

Tags: support, questions, flagging

I wanted to flag https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97699/can-i-travel-to-tibet-independently as off-topic (the question is now deleted), but differently from where I can vote to close a question as off-topic, I cannot select a custom reason. The reasons I could select are not the reason to close the question as off-topic.

> Questions about software development are off-topic here, but can be asked on Stack Overflow. *It's not about software development.*
>
> Questions about pre-release software are off-topic. For more information, see Can we ask about iOS 7 and OS X Mavericks? and Can I ask about not-yet-publicly released OS?. *It's not even about pre-releases.*

I flagged the question for moderation attention, but it doesn't seem right.
I know that flagging the question as off-topic causes the question to be added to the review queue, where other users would be able to vote to close it.

Should I simply leave the task to the users with the privilege of close-voting questions?

In this case, I had another reason to flag the question, since it contained a not necessary link that made it smell like spam. I am asking what I should do for a question I think it should be closed, now that the off-topic close-reason has sub-reasons.

Comment: See also http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1761/do-we-need-a-generic-off-topic-close-reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case, I would have used:

[image: it is spam].

I feel it is a large enough selector to avoid to add ten other selectors which might kill the good will of the garbage collector ☺.

Comment: I know that; that is the reason I said "In this case, I had another reason to flag the question, since it contained a not necessary link that made it smell like spam." `:))` The question is more about what I should do with question that are off-topic, when the predefined reasons don't apply. I can only flag those questions, since I cannot vote to close them.

Comment: In this case, the method you used seems the right one, and better than nothing (Patrix ®).

Answer (score 3):

For most practical purposes the flag reason doesn't matter that much, all flagged posts end up in the same moderator queue at the end. So in any case choosing **a** flag for dubious posts is better than not flagging it at all.

Comment: [Flags to close a question are no longer shown in the moderator only queue.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187008/152859) That is the reason I would prefer to flag to close a question when it should be closed, rather than flagging for moderation attention.